# What do these sets mean? Relational Algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relation-algebra

I'm in a databases class and this homework is due next week. I have been home sick for a couple days so I can't go to class to ask this question right now and I'd hate to waste time, so hopefully someone can help me out on here.

I'm a little confused, this is problem #1:

Problem1 [15′ = 5′ ∗ 3]

Given the following relations $R$ and $S$, where $R(A,B,C) =((x,y,z); (j,g,s);(y,x,g); (q,w,e))$ and $S(B,C,D) = ((g,s,r); (y,x,g); (r,q,e))$ compute the following operations:

1. Cartesian product: $R\times $S;
2. Natural join: $R \bowtie S$;
3. Equal join: $R \bowtie R.B=S.B S$

First: Is there a significance to the [15' = 5' * 3] next to the problem number? each problem has something like that and I'm not sure what's going on or if my teach is being silly.

Second: What is with the $(A,B,C)$ behind $R$? does it relate to the sets on the right side of the equal sign? I took discrete math and I feel confident I can do this work easily enough, but I have a feeling I'm missing out on some key concepts.

If I'm totally wasting time and it'd be too much to try to explain, could someone point me in the direction of a solid tutorial that can explain how this format works? I've been reading the textbook diligently, but the lectures haven't been following the book content very closely it seems.

Comment: For the first question: It most likely means that in an exam, the problem would give 15 points in total, and since it has three subproblems, the 15 points are divided evenly between the subproblems.

Comment: In the terminology of relational algebra, $A,B$, and $C$ are the *attributes* associated with the relation $R$; in more standard mathematical terms, $R$ is a relation on $A\times B\times C$. You might take a look at [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) on relational algebra, which has relevant definitions and examples. (Your *equal join* is its *equijoin*.) I find (1) a little odd though: my understanding is that in this context one normally defines the Cartesian product only for relations that have disjoint sets of attributes.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense now, thanks @mrp.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott At least when I took a course on databases, Cartesian product was defined on sets of attributes in general, but you are right that if the sets of attributes are disjoint, then most join operations simply become the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation is a bit non-standard, so let me try to formulate it in a more standard way. We have four sets $A, B, C, D$, and two relations $R$ and $S$. $R$ is a relation on $A \times B \times C$ and $S$ is a relation on $B \times C \times D$. We are then told that $R$ and $S$ are given as follows.

$$R = \{(x,y,z),(j,g,s),(y,x,g),(q,w,e)\}$$
$$S = \{(g,s,r),(y,x,g),(r,q,e)\}$$

Next we are told to find the

1. Cartesian product of $R$ and $S$,
2. natural join of $R$ and $S$,
3. equal join of $R$ and $S$.

Do you know how to do 1-3?

Comment: If the cartesian product is like the concept from discrete math, I'd come up with something like: 
((x,y,z), (g,s,r); (x,y,z), (y,x,g); (x,y,z), (r,q,e); 
 (j,g,s), (g,s,r); (j,g,s), (y,x,g); (j,g,s), (r,q,e); 
 (y,x,g), (g,s,r); (y,x,g), (y,x,g); (y,x,g), (r,q,e); 
 (q,w,e), (g,s,r); (q,w,e), (y,x,g); (q,w,e), (r,q,e))
Please let me know if that is the wrong approach (or wrong format). For the other two, I was going to read through some tutorials and such and see how they are produced.